# Java: Why does my program receive java.io.FileNotFoundException error for creating an input file when it successfully creates an output file?

Tags: java, exception, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I created two files in this program: "OutputFile.txt" and "InputFile.txt". When I run my code, it displays an error called "java.io.FileNotFoundException" but it created "OutputFile.txt" in my system but not "InputFile.txt"
Why is that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // 2 File objects are created: outFile and inFile, this will create text files in my system
    File outFile = new File("OutputFile.txt");
    File inFile = new File("InputFile.txt");
    
    // These FileWriter Objects are created to allow the File Object to be writable to readable
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outFile);
    FileReader in = new FileReader(inFile);
    
    // these closes files after use in program
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2 File objects are created: outFile and inFile, this will create text files in my system

The first part of this is correct; the second is not. Creation of a `File` object is not creation of a file; `new File(...)` just makes an object that stores a path, basically, and does not touch the disk in any way. Per docs, a `File` object is

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

`FileWriter` and `FileReader` do touch the disk. `FileWriter` writes to a file, and will create one if it does not exist; `FileReader` does not write, it reads — and if the file does not exist, it complains.